# Find the values of both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that the vector $x + \alpha y + \beta z$ is orthogonal to both y and z.

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Given the vectors $x = (1, −4, 3)^T$, $y = (0, 1, 1)^T$ and $z = (2, 0, −1)^T$, find the values of both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that the vector $x + \alpha y + \beta z$ is orthogonal to both $y$ and $z$.

I'm not totally sure where to begin? I think I'm suppose to look at the Null Space of the transpose of a matrix formed of vector y and vector z? If that's the case thought, I see no point to be given an x vector?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cross product of the vectors y and z will give a vector that is perpendicular to both y and z.

The cross product of <0,1,1> and <2,0,-1) is <1,-2,2>.
Setting this equal to the vector x+αy+βz gives $\alpha = -2$ and $\beta = 2$.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the cross product:

You want to find
$a$ and $b$
such that
$V = x+ay+bz$
 is orthogonal 
to both $y$ and $z$.

Then,
using "$\cdot$"
for dot product,
you want
$V\cdot y
=V\cdot z
= 0
$.

$V\cdot y
=(x+ay+bz)\cdot y
= x\cdot y+a (y\cdot y) + b (z\cdot y)
$
and
$V\cdot z
=(x+ay+bz)\cdot z
= x\cdot z+a (y\cdot z) + b (z\cdot z)
$.

You therefore have
two equations in the
two unknowns $a$ and $b$:
$x\cdot y+a (y\cdot y) + b (z\cdot y) = 0$
and
$x\cdot z+a (y\cdot z) + b (z\cdot z)=0$.

Solve these and you are done.

Comment: This is a dumb question, but what would those two equations look like in matrix form in order to solve them? $$ \begin{bmatrix}
        xy & y^2 & zy \\
        xz & yz & z^2 \\
        \end{bmatrix} v = 0$$
Does that look correct?